# how to add HTTPS to ktor server running on Android device

Tags: android, kotlin, ssl-certificate

I'm creating an HTTPS ktor server on my Android device. The question is about the HTTPS part.

I'm following along this tutorial:

https://proandroiddev.com/running-tls-protected-http-server-on-android-using-ktor-49bdbc7f5e1f

I need to create and add a keystore file with extension .bks.

Using this command:

```
./getssl -c yourdomain.com
```

I can create a certificate using a specific domain. But the server runs on a LAN, and is accessed by the local IP. e.g. `192.168.1.10`.

The tutorial talks about these 2 files from the ACME API:

`fullchain.pem` - the certificate file

`privkey.pem` - the private key file for the certificate

Can I just download these or do I need to create them using a specific domain, and if so which domain should I choose because it's a LAN network?

Comment: hello Jim Clermonts, you have resolved this question?. I have the same question. Can share your anwser?

Comment: @Freax posted my answer.

Comment: Thank your anwser. I resolved this question. But my way generate `fullchain.pem` and `prikey.pem` by openssl. Below is my answer

Answer (score 2):

create bks keystore by this [android-ssl-certificate](https://github.com/myfreax/android-ssl-certificate) shell script

```sh
./mkcert.sh
```

configure ktor Engine Environment

```
object SSL {
    private const val AliasName = "demo_alias"
    private const val PASSWORD = "demo_password"

    fun getKeyStore(context:Context): KeyStore {
        return KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType()).apply {
            context.assets.open("keystore.bks").use {
                load(it, getKeyPassword().toCharArray())
            }
        }
    }

    fun getKeyAlias(): String {
        return AliasName
    }

    fun getKeyPassword(): String {
        return PASSWORD
    }

    fun getAliasPassword(): String {
        return PASSWORD
    }

}

fun configureEngineEnvironment(context: Context): ApplicationEngineEnvironment {
    return applicationEngineEnvironment {
        log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ktor.application")
        connector {
            port = Config.HTTPPort
        }
        sslConnector(
            SSL.getKeyStore(context),
            SSL.getKeyAlias(),
            { SSL.getKeyPassword().toCharArray() },
            { SSL.getAliasPassword().toCharArray() }
        ) {
            this.port = Config.HTTPSPort
        }
        modules.add {
            configureRouting(context)
            configureSockets()
            configureMonitoring()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I try apply this solution I have a problem
connector.keyStore.getCe…Chain(connector.keyAlias) must not be null
                                                                                                     at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyChannelInitializer.

Do you have any suggest to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
class HttpServer(private val sslCredentials: SslCredentials, private val context: Context) {

    private val scope =
        CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.IO + CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
            Timber.e(throwable)
        })

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpServer::class.java.simpleName)
    private val server = createServer()

    fun start() {
        server.start()
    }

    private fun createServer(): NettyApplicationEngine {
        return scope.embeddedServer(Netty) {
            // Logs all the requests performed
            install(CallLogging)
            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                gson {}
            }
            install(CORS) {
                anyHost()
                header(HttpHeaders.ContentType)
                header(HttpHeaders.AcceptLanguage)
                header(HttpHeaders.Accept)
                header(HttpHeaders.ContentLanguage)
                header(HttpHeaders.AcceptCharset)
                header(HttpHeaders.AcceptEncoding)
                header(HttpHeaders.AccessControlAllowOrigin)
            }

            routing {
                get("/") {
                    call.respond(mapOf("message" to "Local Network Integration server running. Scan QR or fill in IP address to connect."))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun <TEngine : ApplicationEngine, TConfiguration : ApplicationEngine.Configuration>
            CoroutineScope.embeddedServer(
        factory: ApplicationEngineFactory<TEngine, TConfiguration>,
        module: Application.() -> Unit
    ): TEngine {
        val environment = applicationEngineEnvironment {
            this.parentCoroutineContext = coroutineContext + parentCoroutineContext
            this.log = logger
            this.module(module)

            connector {
                this.port = HTTP_PORT
            }

            sslConnector(
                sslCredentials.getKeyStore(),
                sslCredentials.getKeyAlias(),
                { sslCredentials.getKeyPassword().toCharArray() },
                { sslCredentials.getAliasPassword().toCharArray() }
            ) {
                this.port = HTTPS_PORT
                this.keyStorePath = sslCredentials.getKeyStoreFile()
            }
        }

        return embeddedServer(factory, environment)
    }

    fun stop() {
        server.stop(0, 0)
        scope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
    }

    companion object {
        const val HTTP_PORT = 8080
        const val HTTPS_PORT = 8443
    }
}

interface SslCredentials {

    fun getKeyStoreFile(): File

    fun getKeyStore(): KeyStore

    fun getKeyAlias(): String

    fun getKeyPassword(): String

    fun getAliasPassword(): String
}

class KeyStoreFactory {

    companion object {
        init {
            Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider());
        }
    }

    private fun chainProvider() = ChainProvider.test()

    fun generate(ip: String): KeyStore {
        val keyPair = createKeyPair()

        val store: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS", "BC")
        store.load(null, null)
        store.setKeyEntry(
            CompanySslCredentials.ALIAS,
            keyPair.private,
            CompanySslCredentials.PASSWORD.toCharArray(),
            arrayOf(
                generateSelfSignedCertificate(keyPair, ip),
                chainProvider().getIntermediateCertificate(),
                chainProvider().getRootCertificate()
            )
        )

        return store
    }

    fun createKeyPair(): KeyPair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC").genKeyPair()

    fun generateSelfSignedCertificate(keyPair: KeyPair, ip: String): X509Certificate {
        val subjectAltNames =
            GeneralNames.getInstance(DERSequence(arrayOf(GeneralName(GeneralName.iPAddress, ip))))

        val x500Name =
            X500Name(" C=XX, ST=XX, L=XX, O=XX, OU=XX CN=XX")
        val certificateBuilder: X509v3CertificateBuilder = JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(
            chainProvider().getIntermediateCertificate(),
            BigInteger.valueOf(Instant.now().toEpochMilli()),
            Date.from(Instant.now()),
            Date.from(Instant.now().plus(Duration.ofDays(365))),
            x500Name,
            keyPair.public
        )
            .addExtension(
                ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.35"),
                false,
                AuthorityKeyIdentifier(
                    SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(
                        ASN1Sequence.getInstance(chainProvider().getIntermediatePublicKey().encoded)
                    )
                )
            )
            .addExtension(ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.19"), false, BasicConstraints(false))
            .addExtension(
                ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.15"),
                true,
                X509KeyUsage(
                    X509KeyUsage.digitalSignature or
                            X509KeyUsage.nonRepudiation or
                            X509KeyUsage.keyEncipherment or
                            X509KeyUsage.dataEncipherment
                )
            )
            .addExtension(Extension.subjectAlternativeName, false, subjectAltNames)

        return JcaX509CertificateConverter()
            .setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())
            .getCertificate(
                certificateBuilder.build(
                    JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSAEncryption").build(
                        chainProvider().getIntermediatePrivateKey()
                    )
                )
            )
    }
}

class CompanySslCredentials(private val context: Context) : SslCredentials {

    override fun getKeyStoreFile(): File {
        val directory = context.getDir("Downloads", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val file = File(directory, "keyfilecompany")
        file.createNewFile()

        try {
            val inputStream = context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.keyfile)
            val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            val buf = ByteArray(1024)
            var len: Int
            while (inputStream.read(buf).also { len = it } > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buf, 0, len)
            }
            fileOutputStream.close()
            inputStream.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return file
    }

    override fun getKeyStore(): KeyStore {
        return KeyStoreFactory().generate(InternetUtil(context).getIpAddress())
    }

    override fun getKeyAlias(): String {
        return ALIAS
    }

    override fun getKeyPassword(): String {
        return PASSWORD
    }

    override fun getAliasPassword(): String {
        return PASSWORD
    }

    companion object {
        const val ALIAS = "company-local-test"
        const val PASSWORD = "XXXXX"
    }
}

abstract class AbstractChainProvider : ChainProvider {

    private val certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
    private val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")

    protected fun toPublicKey(str: String): PublicKey {
        val publicKeyPEM: String = str
            .replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
            .replace(System.lineSeparator(), "")
            .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "")

        val decoded = Base64.decode(publicKeyPEM)
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(X509EncodedKeySpec(decoded))
    }

    protected fun toCertificate(intermediateCa: String): X509Certificate {
        return certificateFactory
            .generateCertificate(intermediateCa.byteInputStream()) as X509Certificate
    }

    protected fun toPrivateKey(intermediatePrivateKey: String): PrivateKey {
        val privateKeyPEM: String = intermediatePrivateKey
            .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .replace(System.lineSeparator(), "")
            .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")

        return keyFactory.generatePrivate(PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(privateKeyPEM)))
    }
}

interface ChainProvider {

    companion object {
        fun test() : ChainProvider {
            return TestChainProvider()
        }

        fun live() : ChainProvider {
            TODO()
        }
    }

    fun getRootCertificate() : X509Certificate
    fun getIntermediateCertificate() : X509Certificate
    fun getIntermediatePrivateKey() : PrivateKey
    fun getIntermediatePublicKey() : PublicKey
    fun getIntermediateKeyPair(): KeyPair = KeyPair(getIntermediatePublicKey(), getIntermediatePrivateKey())

}

class LiveChainProvider : AbstractChainProvider() {

    private val ROOT_CA = """
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
        .
        .
        .

        -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    """.trimIndent()

    private val INTERMEDIATE_CA = """
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
        .
        .
        .

        -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    """.trimIndent()

    private val INTERMEDIATE_PRIVATE_KEY = """
        -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
        .
        .
        .
        -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
    """.trimIndent()

    private val INTERMEDIATE_PUBLIC_KEY = """
        -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
        .
        .
        .
        -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    """.trimIndent()

    override fun getRootCertificate(): X509Certificate = toCertificate(ROOT_CA)
    override fun getIntermediateCertificate(): X509Certificate = toCertificate(INTERMEDIATE_CA)
    override fun getIntermediatePrivateKey(): PrivateKey = toPrivateKey(INTERMEDIATE_PRIVATE_KEY)
    override fun getIntermediatePublicKey(): PublicKey = toPublicKey(INTERMEDIATE_PUBLIC_KEY)
}
```